# Order by first results that do not go over

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How can you order by two fields based on the value not being greater than another? Here is an example of what I have written.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM contest_results r
  LEFT 
  JOIN participant_users u
    ON r.participant_id = u.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN contest_entry_tie_answers t
    ON u.id = t.participant_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN contest_answers a
    ON a.question_id = t.tie_breaker_question_id
 WHERE r.contest_id = 20
 ORDER BY r.correct_answers DESC,
 t.answer <= a.possible_answer ASC
```

Now imagine that this query returns two rows and `contest_entry_tie_answers`.`answer` has a value of 103 and another of 106. Finally, imagine that `contest_answers`.`possible_answer` has a value of 105 because that field was checked as the correct answer. I want to be able to order the results as `contest_entry_tie_answers`.`answer` <= `contest_answers`.`possible_answer`.

That would mean the 103 answer would be shown first in the event that the previous order by `contest_results`.`correct_answers` returns a tie value for both. Then the 106 result would show last because it went over the actual correct answer of 105.

Is there a way to do this? I hope this made some sense.

Comment: wouldn't you have to build the field first then reference it in the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Can you explain with an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the solution by doing the following:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM contest_results r
  LEFT 
  JOIN participant_users u
    ON r.participant_id = u.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN contest_entry_tie_answers t
    ON u.id = t.participant_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN contest_answers a
    ON a.question_id = t.tie_breaker_question_id
 WHERE r.contest_id = 20
 ORDER BY r.correct_answers DESC,
 case 
     when t.answer <= a.possible_answer then 0 
     when t.answer > a.possible_answer then 1
 end,
 t.answer
 DESC
```

This seems to work well from my initial testing.